# Set condition based on duplicate and date

Tags: excel

I have a file with data in column A and dates in column B. The data in column A can have duplicate entries. I'm looking for a way to set column C equal to TRUE for the latest date for each entry i.e. a unique string in column A would always be TRUE, but only the latest date for the duplicate would be TRUE.

In the example below I'm using fruit as the data, with duplicates highlighted in yellow. Here you can see Orange and Banana only occur once so are both set to TRUE. Apple occurs 3 times (Aug 4th, Sep 1st, Sep 2nd) with Sep 2nd being the latest date so is set to TRUE while the other Apple entries are set to FALSE.

[image: Excel sample image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AGGREGATE` function:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(A2=$A$2:$A$6)*($B$2:$B$6),1)=B2
```

[image]

Explanation:

The `AGGREGATE` function returns the first largest value of an array that is calculated in `(A2=$A$2:$A$6)*($B$2:$B$6)`:

1. `(A2=$A$2:$A$6)` - compares the current value of cell `A2` with range `A2:A6` and returns a bool array `{TRUE; FALSE; TRUE; FALSE; TRUE}`
2. `($B$2:$B$6)` simply returns date array from range `B2:B6` - `{01.09; 03.09; 04.08; 25.08; 02.09}`

Multiplying these two arrays yields `{01.09; 0; 04.08; 0; 02.09}` from which the `AGGREGATE` function returns `02.09`, which in turn is compared with the date in cell `B2` and returns `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Any chance you could explain how it works? I googled AGGREGATE and I see you are using the LARGE function. but I can't figure out the rest. Sorry I'm an Excel noob. Thanks